# how can upload image and video with cloudinary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, cloudinary

```
const Profile = () => {
  
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");

  const send = async (event) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append("upload_preset", "*****");
    await axios
      .post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/*****/upload", data)
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
     .catch((err)=>console.log(err)) console.log(data)
  };

  return (
    <div className="card" style={{ marginTop: "20px", width: "500px" }}>
      <form action="#">
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={(event) => {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            setFile(file);
          }}
        />
      </form>
      <button onClick={send}>Upload</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

I want to upload images and videos with culinary, I tried in my app but the error network
but in another app, it works with the same code

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: nerwork error no data found for response

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the request/response headers from the Network tab?